# Color "transparent" not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-content

I have a problem with the IE (what else?):

I generate content with CSS which has also a background-image.
I looks like that:

```
#nav ul li:after {
    content: "--";
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99;
    background: transparent url(image.png);
    color: transparent;
}
```

The text color is in non-IE-browsers transparent, but in all IE browsers (IE6-IE8) it's black and you could see it.
How could I make the text transparent/unvisible?

I tried already: visibility - opacity - filter - text-indent ...
But none did his job right, either it disappears (with it background which I need) or the attribute doesn't apply.

Comment: Which IE version? To clarify, there is a black `--` and that's what you don't want, right? It's not the whole thing that has a black background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get it: With the correct padding and a zero font-size!  Set the padding-left value to be one pixel beyond the image width.

Comment: you may want to expand on this answer with more detail.

Comment: I don't have the project online but I found this changed CSS: `#nav li:after { content: "."; padding: 5px 0px 3px 0px; color: transparent; background: transparent url(bg-nav.png) no-repeat 0px 0px; position: relative; z-index: 1; }`

Answer (score 42):

if what you're trying to do is show the image as background and not showing the text use

`font-size:0px`

it works!

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for this simple answer. Was trying to hide unwanted value of a button with no access to underlying code and this worked.

Comment: OMG this just prevented me from possibly throwing my laptop out the window. Thanks =]

Comment: This causes accessibility issues and shows a small line of text on some older browsers. See the CSS tricks image replacement gallery for more info.

Answer (score 7):

what about using line-height

`line-height:0;`

it worked in my case.

Answer (score 4):

If this doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8

```
font-size: 0;
```

make sure you're using a valid doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work. If it doesn't add display: block or inline-block

```
.transparent {
    text-indent: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I had set body overflow to auto. This was causing an issue rendering color:transparent for an angular component in chrome. Making it visible again (default overflow setting) solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think no versions of IE support `color: transparent`
Perhaps you could try to do it with jQuery or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you already fixed this, but lately i've used a very large line-height, when text-indent is giving me layout problems, combined with overflow: hidden to hide the text.

Answer (score 0):

IE doesn't support `li:after` consistently. Which IE are you talking about? IE6? IE7? Both?

Answer (score 0):

For me color:transparent was not working in IE8, and it was showing text with default color. I used visibility:hidden; for IE8 only as the text was not required to display.

Hope this help in case, if the element is not required to display.

Answer (score -1):

I see you're using a PNG as your background image. Normally, if you're using IE 6, there is a fix for PNG transparency (http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). Even so, this will not work with background-images. So if you're using IE 6, there really isn't a fix.

Comment: If I understand him correctly, he is talking about the `color: transparent` that is not working, not the background.

Comment: @Pekka: Yes, I thought so too, but why have an image on the background if you want said BG to be transparent? Why set the "color" property to transparent as well? That makes no sense. And containers are transparent by default anyway. There are a lot of disconnects here.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but where does it say that the OP is using a transparent PNG?