# color transparent not working in IE

Tags: html, css

I can able to get this functionality in Firefox and chrome. but below code, text is displaying in IE. that text should not display.

```
<a target="_blank" href="#">edit</a> 
<style>
    a {
        background: url("../images/edit1.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
        color: transparent !important;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790181/color-transparent-not-working

Comment: Why not make the link the same color as the color of its underlying container? If it's inside a white div, just make the link white.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly IE 5-8 does not support the transparency property. But IE 9 will support it.

While searching for my blog i found the following method

```
.transparent {
/* Required for IE 5, 6, 7 */
/* ...or something to trigger hasLayout, like zoom: 1; */
width: 100%; 

/* Theoretically for IE 8 & 9 (more valid) */   
/* ...but not required as filter works too */
/* should come BEFORE filter */
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";

/* This works in IE 8 & 9 too */
/* ... but also 5, 6, 7 */
filter: alpha(opacity=50);

/* Older than Firefox 0.9 */
-moz-opacity:0.5;

/* Safari 1.x (pre WebKit!) */
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;

/* Modern!
/* Firefox 0.9+, Safari 2?, Chrome any?
/* Opera 9+, IE 9+ */
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

And

```
.transparent {
zoom: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

I referred this in [Blog 1](http://vivekdragon.wordpress.com/) and [Blog 2](http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/)